# Shopify uninstall webhook requesting uninstall url when installing app

Tags: shopify

I have an issue where my Shopify webhook to handle when a shop uninstalls my app is firing my uninstall route when installing the app.  If I uninstall the app my uninstall route is fired as expected.  I just don't understand why it fires when the app is installed.

Is there something wrong with my webhook?

This is my webhook code:

```
$webhook = $this->sh->call([
            'URL' => 'https://'.$shop.'/admin/webhooks.json',
            'METHOD' => 'POST',
            'DATA' =>   array (
                    'webhook' => array (
                         'topic' => 'app/uninstalled',
                         'address' => 'https://myserver.homelinux.com/uninstall',
                         'format' => 'json',
                        )
                    )
            ], false);
```

I call this code when the shop has accepted the payment transaction.  Immediately it requests my `address` url `https://myserver.homelinux.com/uninstall`

My understanding is that this should register the webhook and only request this address when the shop uninstalls the app.

Any help/advice with this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted above is fine, the problem was elsewhere.  My logic is now the following and works as expected:

```
if($this->isNotActive($shop)){
    $this->registerUninstallWebHook($shop);
}
```

Comment: May you tell me, what actually you did..?